# Unable to locate element using ID or Name

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver, webdriverwait

HTML:

```
<input name="txtAnswer" type="text" maxlength="20" id="txtAnswer" class="box1">
```

Code trials:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='tblSecurityAnswer']//tbody//tr[2]//td[2]//input[@id='txtAnswer']")).sendKeys("green");
```

and also:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//tr:nth-child(1) > td > table > tbody >
    // tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2)"));

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriver driver;

    // IE webdriver
    // System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    // driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();

    // Maximize the browser window
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    // navigate to specified url
    driver.get("http://dxbqcapp01/molforms/login.aspx");

    driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserName")).sendKeys("MS200963915");
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("test@123");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='Submit']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtAnswer")).sendKeys("green");
```

Comment: Update the error stack trace

Comment: Have you checked to see if your element is in an `IFRAME`? Have you tried a wait? Also, please edit your question and add what isn't working, error/exception messages, etc.

Comment: No element not in IFRAME. and i tried to wait but also not work , error that appear is org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"txtAnswer"}

Comment: can you share the html script of the table and element as well

Comment: HTML for element is (<input name="txtAnswer" type="text" maxlength="20" id="txtAnswer" class="box1">) .but after i run the code and i got error that unable to locate element, when try to inspect element again at automated chrome page it view this HTML:                                                                                                                                                           
 </head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="./SecurityAuthentication.aspx?type=1" id="form1">
<div>

Comment: please find recording video for my test case https://www.screencast.com/t/uddlZPT8HpUD

Comment: i am not get any replay about my question

Answer (score 0):

The error stack trace would have helped us to debug your issue in a better way. However to send a *character sequence* to the desired element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.box1#txtAnswer"))).sendKeys("green");
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='box1' and @id='txtAnswer']"))).sendKeys("green");
  ```